# Jaspersoft Studio : issues while drawing graph

Tags: csv, charts, jasper-reports

I am new to *JasperReports* / *Jaspersoft Studio* and struggling a bit with Charts. The experts may find it very primitive and it is possible that I could be missing some very basic stuff here.. Here is a brief of what I am trying to do
1) Data source is csv with following fields
Sr_No,  URI,    total_time_taken,   no_of_requests, avg_time_per_req,   most_expensive_req, timestamp_of_exp_req 
2) The csv has around 40,000 lines in it
3) I want to create a report which has all the 40,000 lines in it (A simple columnar report based on all the fields, sorted by no_of_requests in descending order). This is piece of cake in JasperStudio !
4) Next, I want a summary page with "top 10" URIs in a pie chart where value of the pie series is no_of_requests and key is URI (Pretty straight forward)

I have created a report in JasperStudio with data source as csv. I have selected all the fields and applied no filter to my query for the primary dataset (i.e. the default dataset that I get while creating the report). This helps me print all the 40,000 lines in the "Details" band of the report...so the first part is taken care off.

For summary page I need a pie chart where my challenge is to get "top 10" records from the entire dataset. Thankfully my "top" criteria is based on no_of_requests field and my data is already sorted based on that field. Still, I need a subset of the data to draw a meaningful chart. To achieve this, I tried to create a new dataset with just two fields, the URI (which is the key for the Pie) and no_of_requests (which is the value). I also applied  filter expression "($V{REPORT_COUNT} > new Integer(10)) ? false : true" to the my new dataset so that I get "top 10" records from my already sorted data. I verified that the filter is working correctly by running it in "Data Preview" tab of "Dataset and Query" dialogue. I have chosen the new dataset as the "Dataset" for my Pie chart..

When I run the report (in preview mode of JasperStudio), I get 40,00 0 lines printed corrected (in the Details band) but the summary is empty. It draws no pie chart. 
I tried same with a Bar Chart, but result is the same. The summary in that case shows just X and Y axis with no data points. The graph is empty.

Am I missing something?

Any help in this regards will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created two variables which I am gonna use in my pie chart to select the Top N Values from the Dataset. To achieve This I have used $V{REPORT_COUNT} Variable as follows

IF($V{REPORT_COUNT}<=N,$F{Your_Field},"") - If the Variable is a String IF($V{REPORT_COUNT}<=N,$F{Your_Variable},0) - If the Variable is Integer.

Substitute N with your desired number.If you need top 10 values then N=10

Now I have used these two Variables to create my Pie Chart.

I have written a blog for the same as I could not upload images here.

Please do check the same for detailed solution.

http://www.rajeshsirsikar.com/selecting-top-n-values-from-a-csv-datasource-jaspersoft-studio/

Comment: Though it does not answer my primary question of using a "new" dataset for populating the graph, I must appreciate that this is a good work around ! Thanks ! I am marking this answer as "Correct"